# how can i access data property in html template using loop in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to use data property commentsToShow in my html template to limit the amount of data that displays on my webpage

this is my template

```
<div  v-if="index < products.length" v-for="(commentIndex, index) in computedProduct">
<div class="title pt-4 pb-1">{{products[index].title}}</div>
</div>
```

if i add  `commentsToShow` in my for loop i get one product but the computed products doesn't work same way the other way round

this my script tag

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
         commentsToShow: 1,
      totalComments: 0,
         
    };
  },

  computed: {
   computedProduct() {
      let tempRecipes = this.products;
      if (this.filterPrice !== "true");  
  }
};
</script>
```

if i change computed property to commentsToShow this the error i get in my console

```
The computed property "commentsToShow" is already defined in data.
```

please how can i get the value of `commentToShow` in my template

Comment: You can use a computed property that returns the list with the comments you want to show, and then in your html just use the v-for to iterate that list.

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen please how

Answer (score 0):

according to vue's official docs it's not recommended to use `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element
try using v-if on a wrapper div or template element

```
<div v-for="(commentIndex, index) in computedProduct">
  <template v-if="index < products.length">
    <div class="title pt-4 pb-1">{{products[index].title}}</div>
  </template>
</div>
```

`v-if` has higher priority so it's executed first and `index` will not be defined yet.
also you have to return something on your computed property function in order to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice method on a computed property, like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            commentsToShow: 1,
            allComments: []
        };
    },
    computed: {
        listComments() {
            return allComments.slice(0, commentsToShow);
        }
    };
</script>
```

You can also use pages to show the comments, in this case you can return like this:

```
return allComments.slice((currentPage - 1) * commentToShow, commentsToShow);
```

The first argument of slice is the start index, the second is the number of elements to get

Answer (score 0):

> The computed property "commentsToShow" is already defined in data.

Equivalently how you cannot have more than one variable with the same name defined in a scope. A computed property cannot have the same name as an existing data property. Essentially, they co-exist in the same namespace, thus they have to be unique.

You have a name clash, and that is what the error is saying.